# Change line-height property relative to old line-height value

Tags: javascript, css, space

Is there any solution to change line-height relative to old value of line-height and decrease or increase it?

(My goal is to increase or decrease line-height in webView in android but I know I can do it with some css or javascript so question tag is javascript and css.)

Comment: for example line-height is set to 12 px and i want to increase it ten by ten(22 , 32, 42 , ...)

Comment: @mohammadhoseinabedini I have answered that below.

Comment: @torazaburo That is only true when no unit is specified for `line-height`. A length unit can be specified.

Comment: @torazaburo So, why did you say that this couldn't be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, yes.

```js
// Get a reference to the element to be changed
var theP = document.querySelector("p");

// Set up a click event handler for the button
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Get the numeric portion of the current line-height property
  var h = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(theP, null).lineHeight);
  
  // Set the new value to twice the old value and add the unit back on to the string
  theP.style.lineHeight = (h * 2) + "px";
});
```

```css
p { line-height:10px; }
```

```html
<button>Double the line height</button>
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.<br>But, when he did, the dog bit his tail</p>
```

Comment: I want to do it without any button because my button is in android if you do me this favor I will thanx to you(forgive me because of my bad english lang) @ScottMarcus

Comment: @mohammadhoseinabedini So when do you want the `line-height` changed? If you don't want the button (or some trigger), just use the code inside the `click ` event handler.

Comment: I have a function in my android activity and a button in it, when I pressed it this function called and change the line-height with your java script code @ScottMarcus

Comment: So you do have a button or you don't? When would you "like" to have the `line-height` changed? If not on a button click, then when?